# Google sheets clock in

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm running a small business, and I need a clock in and out system. I'm trying to get it to work using google sheets and their built in ide, but I'm struggling to figure this out. Could anyone give me a hand, I have screenshots and the code pasted below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtRNh.png)

```
    function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName). setValue(value);
}

function getValue (cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}

//this repeats over and again and I deleted the extra
function setE1() {
  setValue('D1', 'E-1');
}

function addRecord(a, b, c) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a);
  setValue('B' + row, b);
  setValue('C' + row, c);
}

function punchIn() {
 addRecord(getValue('D1'),new Date(), 'Clock In');
}

function punchOut() {
  addRecord(getValue('D1'), new Date(), 'Clock Out');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please specify any errors/issues you've encountered, so answers can be tailored to your needs.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to add up all the total time a specific person has been clocked into for. Currently it shows what time they clock in and what time they clock out, but is there anyway to add up the total time they put in for each week